# JavaMail requires an InputStreamSource that creates a fresh stream for every call

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send an attachment using JavaMail via Spring 2.5's MailSender, but I keep getting this error:

```
Passed-in Resource contains an open stream: invalid argument.
JavaMail requires an InputStreamSource that creates a fresh stream for every call.
```

I am using an `InputStreamResource` :

```
InputStream crofileInputStream = emailDraft.getAttachmentCroFile().getInputStream();
InputStream nacfileInputStream = emailDraft.getAttachmentNacFile().getInputStream();
InputStream sourcefileInputStream = emailDraft.getAttachmentSourceFile().getInputStream();

InputStreamSource[] attachments = {new InputStreamResource(crofileInputStream),new InputStreamResource(nacfileInputStream),new InputStreamResource(sourcefileInputStream)};

sentEmailLog = mailSenderService.sendMIMEMessage(emailDraft, attachmentFileNames, attachments);
```

this last instruction calls 
`MimeMessageHelper.addAttachment(fileName,attachments[i])` for each attachment.

Please how could i solve this issue ?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: By not using an `InputStreamSource`. Assuing that your `getAttachmentCroFile()` returns a `java.io.File` use a `FileSystemResource` instead.

Comment: JavaMail needs to be able to read the data twice - once to determine what encoding to use, and once to do the encoding.  That's why passing it an open InputStream won't work.

Answer (score 14):

Try to use [`javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html)

```
String mailTo = message.getHeaders().get("emailAddress", String.class); 
MimeMessage mimeMessage = sender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
ByteArrayDataSource attachment = new ByteArrayDataSource(message.getPayload(), "application/octet-stream");
helper.addAttachment("document.zip", attachment);
helper.setText("text content of the email");
```

You could also check this example: 
https://www.javatips.net/api/javax.mail.util.bytearraydatasource